# bash - if return code >=1 re run script, start at the beginning

Tags: bash, shell, goto

I have a bash script that prints a heading and tests for a value of "Y" or "N".

When someone enters text that does not equal "Y" or "N", I would like to send them back to the beginning of the script, so it prints the heading and the question again.

I know you can do this with goto but I was wondering if there's a different way because I hear  many individuals say you should not use goto or that it is deprecated. Whether true or not, I'd like to see if anyone else has a way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a direct answer to your question, you can use `exec` to replace the current process with another process, or, as the case may be, another fresh copy of the current process.

```
read -p "Yes? Or no? " yn
case $yn in
  [YyNn]) ;;
  *) exec "$0" "$@"
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

You could implement it in a loop:

```
while [ !$exit_loop ]
do
    echo "enter choice - "
    read -n 1 input
    case "$input" in
     y|Y) $exit_loop = 1;;
     n|N) $exit_loop = 1;;
     *) echo "invalid choice";;
    esac
done
```

Personally I find no difference between using a goto/loop or any other means. I'd always say to use what is most suitable for the situation - for yours, I'd use a goto.

e.g. If you have multiple indentations spanning lots of lines, and you need to jump back to the start of a function, I'd use a goto - it's a lot easier to understand in its context.

Comment: You can simplify with `while true; do` and `case` statement will replace to a simple `if` and if matches, will `break`. So you don't need plus variable (`$exit_loop`).

Comment: Very true. Alas, without knowing what the op wanted to do within the loop, I just threw that together :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more structured approach, you can use a [while or until loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Example](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/scripts/make-links.sh#L184) (slightly simplified) using @Michael's suggestion follows. The exit condition is in the while loop, but the user can also do an intermediary action to decide which action to take:

```
while [[ ! "${action-}" =~ ^[SsRr]$ ]]
do
    echo "What do you want to do?"
    read -n 1 -p $'[d]iff, [s]kip, [S]kip all, [r]eplace, [R]eplace all: \n' action

    if [[ "${action-}" =~ ^[Dd]$ ]]
    then
        diff "$target_path" "$source_path"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this before, [[ ! "${action-}" =~ ^[SsRr]$ ]], neat.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "Hello User, are you ready to learn some Linux?"
while true; do
    echo "Please enter y/n:"
    read a
    bfunc() {
        if [ "$a" == "y" ]
        then
            echo "That is great, lets get started!"
            echo "This Script is under construction, functionality coming soon"
            exit 0
        elif [ "$a" == "n" ]
        then
            echo "That is too bad, see you next time!"
            echo "You are now exiting the script"
            exit 0
        else [ "$a" != "y||n" ]
            echo "Please only enter y or n!" 
        fi
    }
    bfunc
done
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt know that it needed the 4 spaces to make code but this works!

Comment: No it doesn't really; in particular, `else [ "$a" != "y||n" ]` is not a syntax error, but also not at all what you think it is.  Defining the function inside the loop is also quite ... original.

Comment: This is my first bash script, and it does work as I intended it to. Can you explain how it is wrong?